# Can a DC voltage booster be connected directly to a DC to AC inverter?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

I am doing a project on a generator. Instead of using an alternator I am using a dynamo. I then amplify the voltage produced using a DC to DC voltage booster. However, can I get a higher AC voltage by connecting it directly to a DC to AC inverter? I am still green in this topic, I hope you guys could explain it clearly and perhaps you could give some helpful resources.

Comment: What is your problem? Do you need a higher voltage? If so, what voltage? Amperage? Frequency? We also don't know any of the details of your setup. What is your starting voltage for instance?

Comment: Also, resource-request questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE. I suggest that you provide us some specifics to support your objective. Are you trying to generate 110VAC or 220VAC? What are the specific DC voltage in your design. What is the DC booster requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes a DC to DC booster can be connected to DC - AC power inverter. But the key is to define the electrical parameters for your project, and then research for components at will meet you design specification.

For starters there are wide ranged of DC to AC power inverter in the market. Below are two such power inverter example with different VDC inputs and VAC outputs.

1. 12VDC to 110VAC power inverter used in North America automotive aftermarket
2. 415-600 VDC to 480 VAC power inverter used in renewable energy industry

**12VDC to 110VAC Power Inverter**

[image: Automotive Power Inverters]

[image: Automotive Power Inverter Specification]

**415-600 VDC to 480 VAC power inverter**

[image: Renewable Energy Power Inverter]

[image: Renewable Energy Power Inverter specifications]

Depending on your end goal the generator will have to boost the DC voltage to match the power inverter requirements. Other factors to consider wattage of the power inverter, and efficiency to name a few.

I hope this will get you started.

Referances:

- [Your guide to DC to AC POWER INVERTERS](http://www.smps.us/power-inverter.html)
- [Battery Integrated Inverter (3 Port) — BIGI-250 from Princeton Power Systems](http://www.princetonpower.com/products/battery-integrated-inverter-3-port.html)
- [Ultra Compact 150 Watt Power Inverter/Charger](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=&cs=04&sku=A0145295&dgc=ST&cid=293344&lid=5616479&acd=12309152537461010&ven1=sE1inYhPj&ven2=,)